# Does ng-class or ng-style cache a background image?

Tags: angularjs

I know ng-img makes sure any images that are retrieved are stored in browser cache, but when I use either ng-class or ng-style to set a background image, are those stored in the browser cache?

Comment: Images that the browser downloads with say, the background-image css property are automatically cached by the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those explicitly store to the browser cache--the browser does that automatically and without your ability to affect it from the client side (short of requesting a different url).

Comment: So the best approach to disable caching would be to request something like `img.png?nocache=123`...?

Comment: That works when there's no intervening proxies that will cache your request regardless of the fact that there's a query string. Your best bet is to actually change the filename or path to the file.